# Find escaped characters excluding quotes and back ticks

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to detect all escaped characters, excluding quotes and back ticks (`"`, `'`, `` ` ``), in a vector of strings using `grep` but can not arrange the proper regex.  Here is what I've tried:

```
x <- c("i 4like...", NA, "\\rgreat", "\aI like it", "\\", "She said \"yes\"")

grep("\\\\", x) && !grep("\\\"|\\\'|\\\`", x)
```

I would expect the following result:

```
[1] 3 4 5
```

As these elements contain escaped characters that aren't quotes or back ticks.

**Please note that R regex is specific and other forms of regex may not work or need to be adjusted.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something that's not there. When you do

```
grep("\\\\", x)
```

you are actually looking for a literal single backslash in a string. There's one level of escaping to type the backslash in R, and then there's another level to escape the slash in the regular expression itself.

You were expecting a match to

```
"\aI like it"
```

But there's no actual slash in the string itself. If you do `cat(x[4])`, you wont see the slash. The `\a` actually is the "symbol" for the alert bell. See `?Quotes` for allowed escaped characters.

You'll also notice that `grep("\\\\", x)` does not match `"She said \"yes\""`. Again, this is because there are no actual slashes in the string. This is just the way R encodes them by default in the console. you can do `cat(x[6])` to see the un-escaped version and also `nchar(x[6])` to confirm it has 14 characters rather than 16 characters.